# std::future and clang with -stdlib=libstdc++

Tags: c++11, clang, future, libstdc++

The following program fails to link with clang and -stdlib=libstdc++:

```
$ cat future.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main()
{
  std::future<int> f1 = std::async([](){ return 42; });
  f1.wait();
  std::cout << "Magic number is: " << f1.get() << std::endl;
}
$ g++-mp-5 future.cpp -std=c++11 && ./a.out
Magic number is: 42
$ clang++-mp=3.5 future.cpp -std=c++11 && ./a.out
Magic number is: 42
```

When building with clang and -stdlib=libstdc++, the following linking error occurs:

```
$ clang++-mp-3.5  future.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -I/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++ -I/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/x86_64-apple-darwin14 -L/opt/local/lib/gcc5 -lstdc++ && ./a.out 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__once_call", referenced from:
      void std::call_once<void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*>(std::once_flag&, void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*&&)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*&&, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*&&, bool*&&) in future-b6480b.o
      void std::call_once<void (std::thread::*)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread> >(std::once_flag&, void (std::thread::*&&)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread>&&) in future-b6480b.o
  "std::__once_callable", referenced from:
      void std::call_once<void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*>(std::once_flag&, void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*&&)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*&&, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*&&, bool*&&) in future-b6480b.o
      void std::__once_call_impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*)> (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*)> >() in future-b6480b.o
      void std::call_once<void (std::thread::*)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread> >(std::once_flag&, void (std::thread::*&&)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread>&&) in future-b6480b.o
      void std::__once_call_impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (std::thread::*)()> (std::reference_wrapper<std::thread>)> >() in future-b6480b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, a simple program w/o `future` builds just fine, e.g.:

```
$ cat simple.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Magic number is: " << 42 << std::endl;
}
$ clang++-mp-3.5  simple.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -I/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++ -I/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/x86_64-apple-darwin14 -L/opt/local/lib/gcc5 -lstdc++ && ./a.out 
Magic number is: 42
```

System is OSX 10.10.4 with macports.

I can't figure out what is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Update: everything works on Linux [Ubuntu 14.04LTS with clang++-3.5 and gcc-5] it works: `$  clang++-3.5 future.cpp  -std=c++11 -I. -pthread -stdlib=libstdc++ -I/usr/include/c++/5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5  -lstdc++ && ./a.out `. Output: `Magic number is: 42`

Comment: Tried `-pthread` on OSX 10.10.4?

Comment: Yes,  no difference with `-pthread`.

Comment: On Linux, without `-pthread` has different linking error: `future.cpp:(.text+0x33e2): undefined reference to 'pthread_create'`  in `/tmp/future-968e1f.o: In function 'std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>, int>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>, int>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':`

Comment: Add `-nostdinc++`, otherwise there's a chance clang is including wrong headers and check what's linked in with `-v`.

Comment: Adding `-nostdinc++` doesn't fix the problem; reports the same linking error. But `-v` confirms that `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` is not in the include search path anymore, and the provided includes path via `-I` are the first in the list.

Comment: @Evghenii: Try the `-nodefaultlibs` option. Maybe my answer to a "similar" question may help you further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31626106/1392778.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the hint! I also created a [wrapper script](https://gist.github.com/egaburov/2775a4b853b59241101a) suggested by you for libstdc++ mode, but unfortunately this didn't help. Getting the same linking error.

Comment: @Evghenii: Could you add the output of `-v` to your question?

Comment: @Evghenii: Never mind. This is some other incompatibility, gcc emits a reference to `___emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable` and clang to `__ZSt15__once_callable`.

Comment: `libstdc++` was designed for use with GCC; the standard library that comes with Clang is `libc++`. Why would you want to mix them? They are not compatible (not API, and certainly ABI!), and since there's a lot of compiler magic in (not only) modern C++, you shouldn't expect them to compile with a not-explicitly-supported compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an incompatibility between GCC and Clang on Mac OS X.

GCC emits a reference to `___emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable` while clang  emits a reference to `__ZSt15__once_callable`.

Unfortunately, `__ZSt15__once_callable` and `___emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable`
are not compatible, so doing something like:

`asm("__ZSt15__once_callable: jmp ___emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable");`

wouldn't work either.

I also came accross this LLVM bug report: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2014-August/035744.html which probably means clang will never add for support GCC's emutls implementation.

---

**Edit:** It looks like support for emutls was added to clang trunk a couple of hours ago in [r243438](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/dc73dc09f135cb1d36fd18f1918395ddf68cec63) via `-femulated-tls`.

Comment: Thank Thomas for explanation. If understand correctly, there is basically no way to compile program that uses thread local storage with clang and use libstdc++ on OSX.

Comment: @Evghenii: It looks like support for emutls was added to clang trunk a couple of hours ago: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/dc73dc09f135cb1d36fd18f1918395ddf68cec63.

Answer (score 0):

Clang on OSX uses an older version of libstdc++. I believe its version 4.2 which does not support many of the C++11 features. If you want to use C++11 with clang on OSX your only choice is libc++.

You could also use gcc-4.x from homebrew which will include a newer version of libstdc++. Unfortunately clang will not easily link with this version of the standard library.

Comment: I was under the impression that libstdc++ from /opt/local/lib/gcc5 was used [from macport gcc5 port]. Is there a way to know which libstdc++  is actually used by clang [i use clang 3.5 from macports]?

Comment: fwiw, simple.cpp built as shown above appears to use macports libstdc++: `otool -L a.out`  output for libstdc++ `/opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.21.0)`

Comment: I see you are using a different version of clang. I was under the impression you were using the Apple clang compiler which does have an older version. Running that version will throw compiler warnings on my system (OSX 10.9)

Answer (score 0):

Undefined symbol `std::__once_call` when building GCC's standard library is explained here https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5786 and should be fixed when using compiler flag `-femulated-tls`.