# Is it possible to build boost with clang and gcc support?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, g++, clang

I am running into an odd problem, where I need to access boost libraries using both gcc and clang specific modules (these programs interact. One is gcc/g++ exclusive, and one is clang exclusive). Is there any way to build boost so that both modules access the same location when calling boost, but boost is able to facilitate gcc or clang specific requests?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it's questionable if you really should do that.

You would have to choose either to use `libc++` or `libstdc++` with both compilers.

`libstdc++` is definitely the better one since clang can deal with it flawlessly, 
gcc has problems parsing several `libc++` headers.

Something like this should make clang use gcc's `libstdc++` on Mac OS X.

```
clang++ \
  -stdlib=libstdc++ \
  -nostdinc++ \
  -Qunused-arguments \
  -nodefaultlibs \
  <path to>x86_64-apple-darwin14/lib/libstdc++.a \
  <path to>x86_64-apple-darwin14/lib/libsupc++.a \
  <path to>lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.2.0/libgcc.a \
  <path to>lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.2.0/libgcc_eh.a \
  -lc \
  -Wl,-no_compact_unwind \
  -cxx-isystem <path to>x86_64-apple-darwin14/include/c++/5.2.0 \
  -cxx-isystem <path to>x86_64-apple-darwin14/include/c++/5.2.0/x86_64-apple-darwin14 \
  -mmacosx-version-min=10.7.0
```

I recommend to put this in a wrapper script, then pass `CXX=clang++-libstdc++`
to the boost build script.

Example wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ls -l "$@"
```

Wraps ls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am having trouble implementing this - could you please clarify how this can be used as a wrapper?

Comment: @kilojoules: Added an example wrapper script.